Angular Dynamic path with param in the middle activate issue
Here is the issue, I have following paths:
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "client/select/nodes", component: ClientSelectionComponent, canActivate: [MasterGuard], data: { guards: [GUARDS.AUTH] } },
      { path: "client/:clientID/nodes", component: ClientNodesComponent, canActivate: [MasterGuard], data: { guards: [GUARDS.AUTH] } },
    ]
}];


and
<a *ngFor="let item of navItems" [routerLink]="item.url" routerLinkActive="active-tab" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{matrixParams:'ignored', paths:'subset', queryParams:'ignored', fragment:'ignored'}">{{item.name}}</a>

when clicked on client/select/nodes it adds active class to the a element. Because it's a real path exists in the nav-items and routerlinks know about it and this URL loads a client selection component which they select the client from the list and get navigated to /client/:clientID/nodes which actually loads the real page.
I still want the item of /client/select/nodes to get active class by ignoring the path parameter on routerLinkActive attribute.
I have achived this when I turn the URL to be /client/nodes/:clientID because comparing the subset makes sense. However this doesn't give me the feeling that this URL reflects the page intention. It looks like on this URL :clientID is actually a node id: /clients/nodes/1 for example.
I need a way to be able to ignore the path parameter when checking isActive for the URL, so doesn matter what write in between /clients and /nodes, it activates the button for /client/select/nodes.
The real code is much much more complex that this because whole navigation system is a complex component with it's own navItem type of objects and inner calls of itself for dropdown elements etc.
I tried to reduce it down to simplier question that just reflect what I mean and hardcoded answers will not work since the whole system works for dynamic navItem object.

After going over all the documentations and doing tons of search I ended up with such a custom solution as follows:
Router Module
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "client/nodes", component: ClientSelectionComponent, canActivate: [MasterGuard], data: { guards: [GUARDS.AUTH] } },
      { path: "client/:clientID/nodes", component: ClientNodesComponent, canActivate: [MasterGuard], data: { guards: [GUARDS.AUTH] } },
    ]
}];

HTML
<a *ngFor="let item of navItems"
[routerLink]="item.url"
routerLinkActive="active-tab"
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{matrixParams:'ignored', paths:'subset', queryParams:'ignored', fragment:'ignored'}"
class.active-tab]="shouldCustomActivate(navItem)">{{item.name}}</a>

TS
let navItems = [
  {
    name: "Nodes",
    url: "/client/nodes",
    activateAsProxyRegex: "\/client\/[0-9]+\/nodes"
  },
  {
    name: "Lists",
    url: "/client/lists",
    activateAsProxyRegex: "\/client\/[0-9]+\/lists"
  }
]

protected shouldCustomActivate(navItem: NavMenuItem): string {
  let proxyUrl = navItem.activateAsProxyRegex ? navItem.activateAsProxyRegex : '';
  if (proxyUrl === '')
    return "";

  if (!new RegExp(proxyUrl).test(this.router.url))
    return "";

  // this.emitChildSelected(true);
  return "active-tab";
}

